# ¿Cómo descompilar un archivo.war java?

Tags: java, web, war

Buenas, he buscado varias formas de descompilar el war de un proyecto que tengo pero solo obtengo la carpeta Meta-inf y web-inf.

- Intente importarlo desde netbeans como un proyecto con recursos existente.
- Importarlo en Ecilpse Oxygen como proyecto, no encontre la opción para importar desde war.
- Incluso por ahí encontré menciones acerca de que se podía hacerlo online pero no funciona tampoco.

Sigo obteniendo las 2 carpetas pero no los recursos.
Y solo cuento con el war ya que las fuentes no existen y me están solicitando realizar cambios, y yo no conozco mucho acerca del desarrollo en java.
Por eso quería saber cuál es el procedimiento adecuado para obtener las fuentes desde el war.

Comment: Que formas has tratado, agregalas a tu pregunta, aporta más información.revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Archivos war no son nada más que los ZIPs con otro nombre. Los puedes descomprimir con cualquier `unzip`. 
Contienen todos los Html, javascript y las clases de Java. Ten en cuenta que los últimos son compilados con el compilador java y no es tan fácil descompílarlos. Hay herramientas - busca *java decompiler*, pero no se garantiza que obtengas algo con lo que puedas seguir trabajando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podría hacer es desplegar el WAR con Tomcat en su local (por medio de la interfaz Web) e ir a la ruta **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\webapps**, ahí se encontrará el proyecto des compilado

Comment: Sí se encuentra el proyecto pero solo se muestran las 2 carpetas que mencionaba antes, lo que necesito también es la carpeta de los recursos src quiero realizar modificaciones pero no cuento con las fuentes, solo el war.

Comment: ¿ya intentó con WINRAR o WINZIP? si no se descomprime con alguno de estos, cabe la posibilidad de que su archivo WAR esté dañado o que cuando este se generó, no tuviera contenido

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan los datos que encontraras en el empaquetado WAR serán las clases compiladas(bytecode).

Existe un excelente programa que es [JDCompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) y que seguro te pueda ayudar. Toma en cuenta que los archivos decompilados no conservan nombres de variables y algunas cosas no son tan sencillas de compilar pero puedes intentarlo.